# How to change the frontmatter page numbering into (roman)?

Tags: front-matter

How to change the frontmatter page numbering into (roman) "small letter" and the mainmatter change into (arabic). Please see the sample output.

Front matter ( Introduction, Preface)
[image]

mainmatter (Chapters and Sections)

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In particular, please tell us which LaTeX document class you employ. Also, do you need the dashes before and after the lowercase-roman or arabic numerals?

Comment: Please supply a MWE (from ``\documentclass...` to \end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have done and what the problem is.